# Will overstaying a Schengen visa be entered in SIS II?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, overstaying

Long story short, this is my ignorance.

I am an Indian national. I had visa duration for 88 days and I entered the Prague airport before midnight on the 88th day but my fight was the next morning (to Frankfurt). During the security check, the officer told me that I had overstayed and it was recorded as criminal offense. I signed papers and got a receipt (no fine collected) and flew back home.

Now I have few questions:

1. Will this offense (mentioned as criminal) go into the Schengen Information System?
2. Will the public prosecutor proceed with the case or drop it?
3. I have applied for a 3 month long term visa and I have been told by the Embassy that they are waiting a response from MOI of Czech Republic; will the above case affect my visa?
4. Will it be a problem for future Schengen visas (especially when I enter Germany)?

Comment: When you applied for the long term visa, did you tell them about the overstay?  If you didn't and they find out, I suspect they will refuse the visa.

Comment: No. I applied it before 3 months this happened just last week.

Comment: Someone please help

Comment: Not all criminal offences end up in criminal proceedings let alone convictions.

Comment: Srink, in response to your plea to answer the question, nobody here knows whether the public prosecutor will proceed with the case or drop it.  Nobody here knows whether the overstay will affect your visa application, and, even if we did know, there's nothing you can do about it now: you have submitted your application, and all you can do is wait for the embassy to get their response from the Czech MOI, whereafter you will get a response to your application.  When you get it, please come back and post a comment describing the outcome.  Thanks!